# Why is my program not decreasing a life if the answer is wrong?

Tags: python, image, pygame

For my program, I am making a game which involves multiple choice questions. Along with this, I have used three separate heart images to show the lives to the user.

In the code, I set conditions so that if the lives for example is 1, only one heart image is blitted on the screen. The number of lives will only decrease if the answer the user has chosen is incorrect.

Below shows the relevant part of my code:

```
class GameState:
     def __init__(self, difficulty):
         self.difficulty = difficulty

         self.questions = [
             ("Q1: 4 _ 6 = 10?"),
             ("Q2: ___ = 1"),
             ("Q3: 1 * 3?")
         ]
         self.answers = [4, 2, 2]
         self.current_question = None
         self.question_index = 0

     def pop_question(self):
         q = self.questions[0]
         self.questions.remove(q)
         self.current_question = q

         self.question_index += 1

         return q

     def answer(self, answer):
         lives = 3
         if self.answers == self.current_question[1]:
            lives = lives - 1
         else:
            lives = lives

         if lives == 1:
            screen.blit(Heart, (500, 10))

         if lives == 2:
            screen.blit(Heart, (500, 10))
            screen.blit(Heart, (X // 2, 10))

         if lives == 3:
            screen.blit(Heart, (500, 10))
            screen.blit(Heart1, (X // 2, 10))
            screen.blit(Heart2, (775, 10))


class GameScene:

def __init__(self):
    if SimpleScene.FONT == None:
       SimpleScene.FONT = pygame.freetype.SysFont(None, 32)

    self.rects = []

    for n in range(4):
        rect = pygame.Rect(420, (n * 70) + 300, 500, 50)
        self.rects.append(rect)

    self.choices = [['x', '-', '*', '+'], ["number", "fruit", "weather", "letter"], ["4", "3", "-2", "13"]]

     def start(self, gamestate):
         self.background = pygame.Surface((X, Y))
         self.background.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
         self.gamestate = gamestate
         question = gamestate.pop_question()
         SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(self.background, (20, 150), question, (blue))

     def draw(self, screen):
         screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
         n = 0
         for rect in self.rects:
             if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                 pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect)
             pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'),
                              rect, 5)
             screen.blit(Heart, (500, 10))
             screen.blit(Heart1, (X // 2, 10))
             screen.blit(Heart2, (775, 10))

             for i in range(len(self.choices)):
                 if self.gamestate.question_index == i + 1:
                     SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 30, rect. y + 20), str(self.choices[i][n]),
                                         (green))
                     SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 29, rect.y + 19), str(self.choices [i][n]),
                                         (green))
              n += 1

     def update(self, events, dt):
         for event in events:
             if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                n = 1
                for rect in self.rects:
                    if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                       self.gamestate.answer(n)
                       if self.gamestate.questions:
                           return ('GAME', self.gamestate)
                       else:
                           quit()

                    n += 1
```

When I run the program, none of the hearts disappear. Is it because of a mistake I made while setting the condition of the lives to minus by one if the answer is wrong?

Comment: You have an syntax error at this line: `Heart 2 = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Davina/Documents/Hearts.png")`.

Comment: I have a question: Did you type in all of the code instead of copying it?

Comment: Your `lives` variable is local, and is always initialized to 3 at the start of the function.  You probably want it to be an instance variable that's set to 3 in `__init__`.

Comment: @Jakub Szlaur sorry I made a mistake when I typed the code in the question. My actual code doesn't have this error.

Comment: @Davina Please read [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Especially the section about syntax highlighting for code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lives` needs to be an attribute of `GameState`:

```py
class GameState:
    def __init__(self, difficulty):
        # [...]

        self.lives = 3

    # [...]

    def pop_question(self):
        q = self.questions[0]
        self.current_question = q
        return q

    def answer(self, answer):
        if answer != self.answers[self.question_index]:
            self.lives -= 1
        else:
            self.question_index += 1
            self.questions.pop(0)
```

However you must draw the hearts in `GameScene.draw`, dependent on the value of `self.gamestate.lives`:

```py
class GameScene:
    # [...]

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))

        if self.gamestate.lives >= 1:
            screen.blit(Heart, (500, 10))
        if self.gamestate.lives >= 2:
            screen.blit(Heart1, (X // 2, 10))
        if self.gamestate.lives >= 3:
            screen.blit(Heart2, (775, 10))

        n = 0
        for rect in self.rects:
            if rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'), rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, pygame.Color('darkgrey'),
                            rect, 5)

            for i in range(len(self.choices)):
                if self.gamestate.question_index == i:
                    SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 30, rect. y + 20), str(self.choices[i][n]),
                                        (green))
                    SimpleScene.FONT.render_to(screen, (rect.x + 29, rect.y + 19), str(self.choices [i][n]),
                                        (green))
            n += 1
```

---

End the game when

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while True:
    # [...]

        game = scene.update(events, dt)
        if game:
            next_scene, state = game
            if next_scene:
               scene = scenes[next_scene]
               scene.start(state)
            if state and state.lives == 0:
                print("GAME OVER")
                break
```